# How do I construct "quoted expressions" for use in reshape2's dcast?

Tags: r, reshape2

The documentation for reshape2 gives the following detail regarding the subset attribute to dcast:

> ```
> subset quoted expression used to subset data prior to 
>      reshaping, e.g. subset = .(variable=="length").
> ```

However, attempting to use this syntax results in the following error:

```
Error in cast(data, formula, fun.aggregate, ..., subset = subset, fill = fill,  : 
  could not find function "."
```

How do I construct a "quoted expression" for use in subset for dcast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is actually a function provided by the `plyr` package.

using `library(reshape2)` or `require(reshape2)` results in `plyr` being loaded via a namespace and not attached. For the `.(expr)` syntax to work, `plyr` must be explicitly attached.